# spring rest web service @requestparam to method custom class (NOT string)

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-restcontroller

I'm using this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

I want to pass to web service API method parameter other then String:

```
@RestController
public class ApiClass {

   @RequestMapping("/service")
   public int service(@RequestParam(value="paramIn") CustomClass paramIn) {
      if (paramIn.value != 0) return 1;
      else return 0;
  }

}
```

But when I try it I get this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'CustomClass'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [CustomClass]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found`

Thnaks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usual way to do this is to use `POST` or `PUT` method and annotate the the custom object with `@RequestBody`. For example:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/service", 
                 method = RequestMethod.POST, 
                 consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
 public int service(@RequestBody CustomClass paramIn) {

     // do something with the paramIn

 }
```

If you `POST` a JSON representation of your `CustomClass` instance to endpoint `/service` Spring will deserialize it and pass it as an argument to your controller.

Comment: param should be sent as json